# Integral (converges/ diverges)

Tags: calculus

Discuss the convergence of $$\int\limits_2^\infty\dfrac{dx}{x^p\ln(x)}$$ when $p$ is a real parameter.

Comment: Take a look at Bertrand series, it the same thing with series (thus they are the same).

Comment: Do you know Bertrand test?

Comment: Nope, I don’t know, enlighten me

Answer (score 1):

What if there wouldn't be limits? 
$\displaystyle \int\frac{dx}{x^p \log x} = \int e^{-(p-1) \log x}d(\log  x) = \int e^{-(p-1)t} dt$. Now what can you say about value of this integral? And what will be if we add limits ?

Comment: This idea makes the problem much easier than the corresponding problem for series!

Comment: Can you explain further

Comment: @RubaAbuGheith that's your part. You need just calculate value of integral. And check for which $p$ this value exists.